# CesiumJS: How to extrude "LineString" GeoJSON data?

Tags: javascript, json, geojson, cesiumjs

I just started exploring CesiumJS and I want to extrude my GeoJSON building data.

To my understanding thus far, extrudeHeight seems to only work for Polygons. However, my data are in "LineString" format.

The attached codes beneath shows what I have tried so far. May I know what am I doing wrong here? Would greatly appreciate any kind of help I can get!

```
dataSource1.loadUrl('data/buildings.json').then(function(loadedDatasource) {
            viewer.dataSources.add(loadedDatasource);
            var entities = loadedDatasource.entities.entities;
            var colorHash = {};
            for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                var entity = entities[i];
                entity.polyline = new Cesium.ColorMaterialProperty.fromColor(new Cesium.Color(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0));
                entity.polyline.outlineColor = new Cesium.ConstantProperty(new Cesium.Color(1, 1, 1, 0.48));
                entity.polyline.outlineWidth = new Cesium.ConstantProperty(0.5);
                entity.polyline.outline = true;
                entity.polyline.extrudedHeight = new Cesium.ConstantProperty(entity.properties.buildingLevels * 5.0);
                entity.building = true;
            }
        }
```

GeoJSON:

```
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[103.8518324,1.2843096],[103.8522078,1.284276],[103.8522253,1.2842654],[103.8522361,1.2842455],[103.8522209,1.2840604],[103.8521175,1.2840652],[103.8521138,1.2840226],[103.8518128,1.2840482],[103.851781,1.2840535],[103.8517572,1.2840662],[103.8517338,1.2840891],[103.8517138,1.2841128],[103.8517016,1.2841443],[103.851698,1.2841847],[103.8517047,1.2842194],[103.8517208,1.2842492],[103.8517546,1.2842777],[103.851795,1.2842959],[103.8518285,1.2842935],[103.8518324,1.2843096]]},"properties":{"name":"Chevron House","height":"151","building":"yes","old_name":"Caltex House","wikidata":"Q2934405","addr:city":"Singapore","min_height":"16","addr:street":"Raffles Place","roof:colour":"#f9fdfe","addr:country":"SG","addr:postcode":"039803","building:colour":"#f9fdfe","buildingLevels":"33","addr:housenumber":"30","building:min_level":"3"}}
```

Comment: Convert to polygons?

Comment: May I know how do I convert them to polygons?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use Cesium Corridor, as below :

```
var json = {"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[103.8518324,1.2843096],[103.8522078,1.284276],[103.8522253,1.2842654],[103.8522361,1.2842455],[103.8522209,1.2840604],[103.8521175,1.2840652],[103.8521138,1.2840226],[103.8518128,1.2840482],[103.851781,1.2840535],[103.8517572,1.2840662],[103.8517338,1.2840891],[103.8517138,1.2841128],[103.8517016,1.2841443],[103.851698,1.2841847],[103.8517047,1.2842194],[103.8517208,1.2842492],[103.8517546,1.2842777],[103.851795,1.2842959],[103.8518285,1.2842935],[103.8518324,1.2843096]]},"properties":{"name":"Chevron House","height":"151","building":"yes","old_name":"Caltex House","wikidata":"Q2934405","addr:city":"Singapore","min_height":"16","addr:street":"Raffles Place","roof:colour":"#f9fdfe","addr:country":"SG","addr:postcode":"039803","building:colour":"#f9fdfe","buildingLevels":"33","addr:housenumber":"30","building:min_level":"3"}};


var Corridor = viewer.entities.add({
        corridor : {
        positions : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegreesArray(json.geometry.coordinates.flat()),
        height : 100.0,
        extrudedHeight : json.properties.buildingLevels * 5.0,
        width : 1.0,
        cornerType: Cesium.CornerType.BEVELED,
        material : Cesium.Color.BLUE.withAlpha(0.5),
        outline : true, // height or extrudedHeight must be set for outlines to display
        outlineColor : Cesium.Color.WHITE
    }
});
```

[Working example](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Apps/Sandcastle/#c=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)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your LineString's in to Polygons, with [turf.js](https://github.com/Turfjs/turf-line-to-polygon)

```
var line = {
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "LineString",
    "coordinates": [ [ 0,0 ], [ 0,1 ], [ 1,1 ], [ 1,0 ] ]
  }
};

var polygon = turf.lineToPolygon(line);
```

or do it manually, because geojson is very simple format:

```
var crd = line.geometry.coordinates;
var last = c.length - 1; 
if (crd[0][0] !== crd[last][0] || crd[0][1] !== crd[last][1]) {
    crd.push(crd[0]);
}
line.geometry.type = 'Polygon';
line.geometry.coordinates = [crd];
```

Comment: Thanks alot! I managed to get convert them to Polygons and changed to entity.polygon. However, it still doesn't seem to be extruding, do you happen to know if I'm doing anything wrong in my code?

Comment: @ashtonPatel57 create fiddle plz